# How to push a document to a MongoDB set of documents which is unique by one field?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document in mongodb:

```
db.reports.insert({
    selection_type: "views",
    selection_value: "desktop",
    chart_points: [
        {
            date: "2018-01-01",
            value: 1831
        },
        {
            date: "2018-01-02",
            value: 0
        }
    ]
})
```

And I want to **insert or update** an item from `chart_points` based on `date`. I try to use `$addToSet` but that will create a new item in array.

Expected result:

```
{
    date: "2018-01-02",
    value: 2053
}
```

Result after I use `$addToSet`:

```
{
    date: "2018-01-02",
    value: 0
},
{
    date: "2018-01-02",
    value: 2053
}
```

I get that result after I run this query:

```
db.reports.update(
    {},
    {
        $addToSet: {
            chart_points: {
                date: "2018-01-03",
                value: 1876
            }
        }
    }
)
```

NOTE: I have only that document in collection.

Comment: can you provide your update complete query? (query and update part)

Comment: It's just a basic usage of `$addToSet`, also I update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two statements. You can use the [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) in the `$set` to update when the date exists.

```
db.reports.update(
    { "chart_points.date": "2018-01-02" }, 
    { 
        $set: {
            "chart_points.$.value": 2053
        }
    }
)
```

Adding a `$ne` check in the query document will prevent the `$addToSet` from inserting when the date already exists.

```
db.reports.update( 
    { "chart_points.date": { $ne: "2018-01-02"}}, 
    { 
        $addToSet: {
            chart_points: {
                date: "2018-01-02",
                value: 2053
            }
        }
    }
);
```

You can run these back-to-back to get the insert/update functionality you want.